# ListFragment appearing twice on phone

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm seeing an undesired appearance of my list fragment when I run my app on the phone emulator. On the tablet emulator it appears once but on the phone emulator it appears twice. How can I fix this error for the list to appear on the phone emulator only once?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentMainList newFragment = new FragmentMainList();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/master_container"
    android:name="com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.FragmentMainList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentMainList"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"/>
```

**activity_main.xml (sw600dp)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentMainList.java**

```
public class FragmentMainList extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ListView list_main;

    String[] listContent = {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3"
    };

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
        list_main = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listContent);
        list_main.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post activity_main.xml from layout folder? not sw600dp

Comment: They are both there. These are the only two activity_main.xml files I have in the layout folder. **activity_main.xml** is from my layout folder.

Comment: Change it from fragment to RelativeLayout and see what happens.

Comment: OK brilliant it works but I honestly though I had to use the <fragment> tag

Comment: But y? You were using RelativeLayout for tablet UI. If not you can have the code like,  if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            FragmentMainList newFragment = new FragmentMainList();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();mTwoPane = true;
        }

Comment: Can you add your reply as an answer please so I can close this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move the logic to add fragment inside the if loop you have.

Answer (score 1):

Although you've already understood how to make it work, I'll try to explain how to make it work properly.

What you do is in fact this:

- If on small screen - add the fragment statically (in XML)
- If on larger screen - add the fragment dynamically (with FragmentTransaction)

It looks weird that the method by which you get the desired functionality depend on the screen size - there should be no correlation between these factors.

What you ought to do (IMHO) is to add this fragment dynamically in both cases - just change your `Fragment` tag in the first XML to `FrameLayout` and everything will work as expected.